# Prevent parent alarms to activate a child alarm event

Tags: game-maker, events, timer

I'm working on a small game using Gamemaker Studio 2 and I've noticed that my Parent `o_enemy.Alarm[0]` Is activating the Child `enemy_1.Alarm[0]` event.

Both alarms were supposed to be activated under different conditions, (The parent alarm is used for all enemies, but the child alarm is used for the specific enemy) but they seem that they'll activate each other because they share the same name `Alarm[0]`.

I could fix it by setting one of the alarms to `Alarm[1]`, but seeing that I've only a limited amount of 9 Alarms, I think there should be an easier solution to solve this problem.

So far I've tried `Event.inherited()` on the child alarm, but that didn't solved the problem.

Is there a way that a child's Alarm will ignore the conditions of the parent alarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
o_enemy.alarm[0] = value;
```

Try something like this

```
with o_enemy
{
    if object_index != enemy_1
    {
        alarm[0] = value;
    }
}
```